# Configuring DbContext in .NET 6 for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-6.0

First, I show my db-related classes:

**DbContext.cs**

```
    public class BookingDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BookingDbContext(DbContextOptions<BookingDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=password;Database=db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Place>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Address)
                .WithOne(ad => ad.Place)
                .HasForeignKey<Address>(ad => ad.PlaceId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }

        public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BookingDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IPlaceService, PlaceService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPlaceRepository, PlaceRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I created CRUD methods like always, so add, delete, update and get. First 3 methods work without problems, only GET fails.
I get an error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. 
A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. 
If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

Do you know what can be the reason for that? As I said before - when I add, delete something to, from database, everything works fine. Only for get methods I got such an error.

EDIT:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Place>> GetPlaces(bool includeAddress)
{
    if (includeAddress)
    {
       return await _dbContext.Places.Include(a => a.Address).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await _dbContext.Places.ToListAsync();
    }
}

public async Task<Place> GetById(int id)
{
   Place? place = await _dbContext.Places
                .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                .Include(p => p.Address)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

   return place ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Place with id: {id} not found.");
}
```

Comment: Please show your CRUD methods code.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Untested by you can try to update your code  `builder.Services.AddDbContext<BookingDbContext>();`  to include options `options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }` 
and remove the `OnConfiguring`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that, being your DbContext service registered as **Scoped**, its instance will be executed like a Unit of Work, with a short lifetime . Probably your GET procedure performs more than one job, and the instance is disposed before your work is accomplished. You could try to use a **AddDbContextFactory** method:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<BookingDbContext>();
```

and include every job, creating a DbContext, inside a **using** block:

```
using (var db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{

 ...get operation code

}
```

In this way **db** will be surely **disposed after all** get operations.